# when do I hide mobile onboarding hotspots

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, onboarding

We placed a few hotspots in our mobile app, when clicked they show onboarding explanations about a component.

If the user clicks on them, they will disappear, 
but what if he does't? is there a best practice for how long do I keep them on the screen?

What if the hot spot was made to explain an interaction and the user performed it without hitting the hotspot, do I keep the hotspot?

[image]

Comment: Can you track when a user uses a function described in the onboarding hotspots?

Comment: On some of them I can, but others tells you the meaning of an icon for example, so we can't..

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- keep them, as they look 'tap-able' and a user would at least be curious. After they tap and do their onboarding, just remove the hot spot as you would;
- make them draggable, so when a user taps and holds any hot spot, they can swipe the hot spots off the screen. In fact, if they tap and hold you can provide a tiny tooltip to let them know they can drag them all off the screen and not appear again ('drag me off screen to disable all tutorials').
- another option is to have a tutorial toggler on landing/splash screen of the app at the beginning that a user can disable and hence have those hot spots disabled before they see them (a bit chunkier solution though, but more explicit).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Emma
the first point is obvious
the 2nd and 3ed are just strange, why would I want to add so much functionality?? I want to make it as simple as possible, not complicate things.

Comment: No worries. So, they're options. And they might be adding a bit of work to the devs, that's fair enough; however, for the user it'd actually make things a bit clearer. I also disagree that's a lot of work, because I have dev background myself and adding a swipe off + tooltip is quite trivial actual. Splash screen is a bit more work, yes. 
I also have seen hot points draggable off the screen before - it's not a new concept. From user perspective it's just a finger swipe really. Not a tap or menu drill down.
Let me know what you think:)

Comment: can you show me an example of a major app that uses this concept?

Answer (score 1):

If the user performs an interaction without clicking the hotspot, it could mean that they didn't fully understood the instructions, or considered the hotspot not important. Or they missed it.
I'd keep the hotspot only for complex flows, or when I need them to stop and think about what actions they can do next.